# Why fs.readfile benchmark times are very different from crypto.pbkdf2?

Tags: node.js, benchmarking, event-loop, libuv

I'm trying to understand how Nodejs uses libuv threadpool. Turns out there are some modules that uses this threadpool like fs and crypto so I tried this :

```
const crypto = require("crypto")
const start = Date.now()

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    crypto.pbkdf2('a', 'b', 100000, 512, 'sha512', () => {
        console.log(`${i + 1}: ${Date.now() - start}`)
    })
}
```

the results were :

```
1: 1178
2: 1249
3: 1337
4: 1344
5: 2278
```

And that was expected. The default threadpool size is 4, so 4 hashes will finish almost at the same time and the fifth will wait.
But when I do the same thing with fs.readfile() :

```
const start = Date.now()
const fs = require('fs')
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fs.readFile('./test.txt', () => {
        console.log(`${i + 1} : ${Date.now() - start}`)
    })
}
```

I get this:

```
1 : 7
2 : 20
3 : 20
4 : 20
5 : 21
```

There is always one that finishes first and the others finish around the same time. I tried reading the file just twice, the same thing happens one will finish first the second after. I also tried reading it 10 times, same thing. Why is this happening

Edit:

- test.txt is just 5 bytes
- I'm using a quad-core laptop running windows 10

Comment: How big is `test.txt`?  Tiny such that system-call overhead is the main bottleneck?  Medium sized so it fits in RAM, but involves the kernel doing a decent size memcpy into user-space?  Or huge so it's not in disk cache?  Did you evict the file from cache before each run so it has to get read in from disk every time?  What OS?  What CPU / RAM?  (Quad-core desktop vs. many-core Xeon have significantly different memory-bandwidth scaling, for example.)  And if disk is involved, SSD or rotational?

Comment: For small numbers in your latter case I think it's better to use [`process.hrtime`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time). I don't think Date.now() would be reliable

Comment: If `test.txt` is only 5 bytes, the overhead to communicate with another thread may be significant compared to the latency of getting into and out of the kernel for open + read + close system calls (or their Windows equivalents).  Depending on whether the inter-thread communication involves system calls.